# Google fonts wont display correctly

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-font-api

I have a problem with Google Fonts. Google fonts displays correctly almost always. But sometimes page loaded correctly and in few seconds fonts goes like crazy. But not everywhere. I mean one font can be displayed correctly at the header for example and not correctly at another parts of the page at the same time. After page reload everything is OK again.

Problem occurs in Goole Chrome 33 (did not notice it in another browsers) with Open Sans Condensed. Sometimes Arial huge size appears instead of it. If I turn of Google fonts Open Sans text is set in Arial and has the normal size.

```
font: normal 300 1em/normal 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
```

What can it be?